# If a quadratic form $f$ takes the minimum on a triangle in a vertex, what can I say about min of $f$ on edges of a subdivision?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, convex-optimization

Let $f(x)=x^2+y^2$ be the Euclidean square-norm and $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be vertices of a triangle $\Delta$ such that $f$ takes the maximum on $\Delta$ in $C$, the minimum in $A$ and takes the minimum on each edge in a vertex.

Does it hold that for $x$ on the edge $AB$, $f$ takes the minimum on the straight line segment $xC$ in $x$?

Update: I added an assumption later ($f$ takes the minimum on each edge in a vertex) and appologize for the confusion.

Comment: What does it mean "$f$ takes the minimum on $xC$ in $x$"?

Comment: I mean, $xC$ is the straight line segment connecting $x$ and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

The squared distance from the origin $f(x,y)$ is a convex function and $\Delta$ is a triangle, hence a convex set, so we have that $f$ takes its maximum on $\partial\Delta$. We know that the maximum occurs in $C$ and the minimum on $A$, hence $C$ is the farthest point from the origin and $A$ is the closest one. However, $OA$ and $BC$ are free to be orthogonal: in such a case, the minimum of $f$ on $BC$ is attained in the projection of $A$ over $BC$, hence the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Oh my god.. I forgor to include that $f$ takes the minimum on each edge in a vertex.. Thank you anyway, can I still edit the question?

Comment: @PeterFranek: ok, in such a case your claim holds, since such a condition gives $\widehat{OAB}\geq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\widehat{OBC}\geq\frac{\pi}{2}$, and you just need to apply the cosine theorem.

Comment: The first part is clear, but how to apply the cosine theorem I don't see immediately.. But will try to figure it out, thanks for the hint!